# Android - Extend BasicNameValuePair

Tags: android, database

Im trying to develop an application that accesses a database through POST requests and returns values in the database.

Im curious about something tho. what if i wanted to pass a number or a list to the database, such as the list of columns to grab for each row. Is it possible to extend the BasicNameValuePair class to acomplish this, or am i missing the correct way to do this?

Comment: Not sure why you would need NVP. Wouldn't a simple List<String> enough to accomplish what you want?

Comment: @azgolfer, Im following a guide to sending HTTP POST commands to a server and this guide used that. I am using an ArrayList of them at the moment to create the entity for the post command. Is this what yu are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Extending the `BasicNameValuePair` is not going to help you as the parameters of a HTTP request need to be name value pairs. If you want to pass more parameters, add more name value pairs and handle them in the server.

If the number of parameters are high, it would be prudent to use HTTP POST.  If the parameters are going to be complex, it would beneficial to submit the request in a more user-friendly format like JSON or XML and parse it on the server side. However, if it is just the name of the columns of the table row, you can also think of using a format like comma separated list.

`http://mydomain/getdata?id=10&columns=1,2,3,4`

In case of the above, you need to parse the columns from the comma separated list at the server side, whereas you are creating name-value pair for columns as follows:

```
BasicNameValuePair columnData = new BasicNameValuePair("columns", "1,2,3,4");
```